# DocuSign API slow response issue,

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to update envelope document's content using **DocuSign java API**, but DocuSign responds to request in the range from 4 to 38 seconds for the same envelope, with the same parameters.

For example, once it takes 5 seconds, and the second or third API call can take 35 seconds.

I use this endpoint **`PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents`** and in requestBody I put EnvelopeDefinition with nested list of documents, that have documentBase64 content.

Also, parameters **`apply_document_fields`** and **`persist_tabs`** are set to **`true`**.

DocuSign Java client version is "2.9.0".

I tried to run my code on the different environments and from different places (networks), and I can't understand what's the reason for such a big difference in the execution time of this endpoint.

Maybe someone faced such an issue and can hint me some setting I missed or parameters I didn't pass?

It is critical for our project to have a constant execution time less than 30 sec.
I appreciate any of your suggestions. Thanks!

P.S. I have the issue only with the endpoint mentioned above.

The other endpoints like:

**`PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs`**, 
or 
 **`ET/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs`**,      or some others are being executed at more or less at the same time.

Duplicated on github: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/issues/129

Comment: one way to make it faster is use binary transfer instead of base64 encoding. Would you like to try it?

Comment: Binary transfer is possible only for POST request (envelope creation), but I don't need to create a new one, I need to update the documents in the existing envelope.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please Check (Accept) the best answer to your questions. Please upvote all useful answers that you read (both to your questions and to others'). And YES, you can both upvote and check a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Adding (or updating) documents in the DocuSign system is a big job which includes the following (and more):

- If the document is not already in pdf format, it is converted to pdf.
- The pdf is "flattened" to remove any extraneous programs in the pdf.
- The pdf is analyzed and updated to add the tabs and tab values appropriate to the document and envelope.
- Much of the above is done in a dedicated sandbox instance for the specific document to eliminate any chances of the document causing a security problem. (Remember that document files, of all types, are a prime vector for computer viruses.)
- Storing the document on multiple redundant, geographically distinct file storage systems to provide extremely high data storage guarantees.

Bottom line, the above takes time. The time taken scales with document size too. The conversion step takes a long time too.

If the time needed for the exact same set of document updates varies, it is either because of system load or because of our many A/B tests as we work to improve the above processing flow. -- We have active engineering projects to improve all of the above.

### Helping it go faster (or seem to go faster)

If your DocuSign application is sending document files that are over a couple of MB, then you may want to shift to sending the documents in binary format instead of Base64. An example of how to do that with [Java is available](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/controller/examples/EG010ControllerSendBinaryDocs.java).

But the real issue is if your app is adding the documents while a human is twiddling their thumbs. If this is the case, then:

- Update one document at a time and provide status to the user: "Uploading document 1 of 3...done. Uploading document 2 of 3...done. etc"
- Don't block the main thread. Eg, enable the user to go on to other tasks and let the documents update in the background.
- If the user *should* wait for the upload to complete, provide them with both a busy indicator and a countdown.

  The countdown: for my apps, my testing shows how long the max time is. (In your case 35 sec). Then I make a javascript countdown timer for a longer period. And update the count two or three times a second to make things faster.

  Eg for a 35 sec max delay, plan on it taking perhaps twice as long, 70 sec. Then make a counter that starts at 150 and decreases twice a second. Result, the job will always finish before the counter reaches 0. And the user will be "happy" because they see that progress is being made (the counter is decreasing) and it finishes before reaching 0 ("it finished 'early'!")

  The countdown time (much more so than a busy indicator) is an old magician trick of moving the user's focus from the real action to something else (the countdown). It works well. Reference: [Tog on Interface](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201608421).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. We also thought about a spinner, but it's like the last way we will go.
About binary format, as I answered above, it is possible only when you create an envelope, but we don't need a new one, we need to update documents in the existing one, but PUT request does not have such an option.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can send the docs in binary for all of our calls. But the decrease in transmission time, given Internet speeds these days, usually isn't much (unless you have really really big docs).

Comment: No, the summary size of both files is 1MB.
I tried to edit an example you provided for binary sending, I replaced POST with PUT, and added /{envelopeId} (and here I got the same link that is on API "/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}"), but I got an error like "Incorrect data format" or "Incorrect accept data format", don't remember exactly, and in general, it didn't work out.